# How to convert element in list to time format: %m/%d

Tags: python, excel, list, element

I extract a column in excel file as a list and try to extract first 8 sub-elements of each element and convert the digit to time format %m/%d.

Here is my code below:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from datetime import datetime

wb = load_workbook("Book1.xlsx")
ws = wb['Sheet1'] 
column = ws['D']
column_list = [column[x].value for x in range(len(column))]
my_list = column_list[2:]

list_1 = [ x[0:8] for x in my_list ]
list_2 = []
for a in list_1:
    date = datetime.strptime(a, '%y%m%d').strftime('%m/%d')
    list_2.append(date)
print(list_2)
```

Target column:

```
['20220425 Mon', '20220425 Mon', '20220425 Mon', '20220425 Mon', '20220425 Mon', '20220425 Mon', '20220425 Mon', '20220425 Mon', '20220425 Mon', '20220425 Mon', '20220425 Mon', '20220425 Mon', '20220425 Mon', '20220425 Mon', '20220425 Mon', '20220425 Mon', '20220425 Mon', '20220425 Mon', '20220425 Mon', '20220426 Tue', '20220426 Tue', '20220426 Tue']
```

Its perfectly append the first 8 sub-elements of each element into a new list.

```
['20220425', '20220425', '20220425', '20220425', '20220425', '20220425', '20220425', '20220425', '20220425', '20220425', '20220425', '20220425', '20220425', '20220425', '20220425', '20220425', '20220425', '20220425', '20220425', '20220426', '20220426', '20220426']
```

However, I cannot convert the element into date formate %m/%d.

It comes out an error:

```
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\_strptime.py", line 352, in _strptime
    raise ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" %
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 425
```

For what I expect output list should be:

```
['04/25', '04/25', '04/25', '04/25', '04/25', '04/25', '04/25', '04/25', '04/25', '04/25', '04/25', '04/25', '04/25', '04/25', '04/25', '04/25', '04/25', '04/25', '04/25', '04/26', '04/26', '04/26'.....]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing is a failure to parse a the string into a date.

`datetime.strptime('20220425', '%y%m%d')` fails because the year (2022) is represented as 4 digits, not 2 digits.

To correctly parse, use `%Y` instead of `%y`

From the python docs on [format codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

> %y  -  Year without century as a zero-padded decimal number.
>
> %Y  -  Year with century as a decimal number.

Starting from the list given in the question, we can store the formatted result like this:

```py
list_1 = ['20220425', '20220425', '20220425', '20220425', '20220425', '20220425', '20220425', '20220425', '20220425', '20220425', '20220425', '20220425', '20220425', '20220425', '20220425', '20220425', '20220425', '20220425', '20220425', '20220426', '20220426', '20220426']
list_2 = []
for a in list_1:
    list_2.append(datetime.strptime(a, '%Y%m%d').strftime('%m/%d'))

print(list_2) # should be ['04/25', '04/25', '04/25', '04/25', '04/25', '04/25', '04/25', '04/25', '04/25', '04/25', '04/25', '04/25', '04/25', '04/25', '04/25', '04/25', '04/25', '04/25', '04/25', '04/26', '04/26', '04/26']
```

Comment: But if I use  use %Y instead of %y, it comes out another error.   ```raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data 'Date' does not match format '%Y%m%d'```

Comment: I've updated the answer to include instructions on how to format the dates seen in the original question.

It looks like you've hit a different error. There isn't enough information to fully diagnose this new issue, but maybe the column header in the xlsx workbook is "Date" and you forgot to exclude it from the values you're trying to parse as dates?